# How add to database hash password in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I make validation form registration using Laravel 9 and now I want to add correct data to database. This is my code in controller

```
public function store(RegistrationRequest $request)
{
    return redirect(
        route(
            'index.store',
            ['registration' => User::create($request->validated())]
        )
    );
}
```

But my problem is that I want to insert to database hash password. In model I have function which hash password but I don't know how to insert to database.

```
class User extends Model
{
use HasFactory;

protected $fillable = [
    'login', 'password', 'email'
];

public function opinions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Opinion::class);
}

public function setPassword($value)
{
    $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($value);
}
```

}

I will gratefull if some help me how resolve this problem.

Comment: Did you add password to fillables array?

Comment: @BilalMaqsood Yes I add password to fillables, I modified my code and show all User model

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using laravel 9 you have two option to store hashed password .Add this mutator in model

```
protected function password(): Attribute
{
   return Attribute::make(
        set: fn($value) => bcrypt($value),
    );
}
```

Ref :[defining-a-mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator)

or older way is

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
{
     $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($value);
}
```

Ref: [Defining A Mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators)